Selecting most recent date in slicer
I need to select the most recent date slicer dynamically in this specific tab. My current code selects all of the dates listed in the slicer.
Sub maxdateslicer()
Sheets("FIP").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("slicer_Execution_Date1")
    .ClearManualFilter
    For Each myitem In .SlicerItems
        myitem.Selected = CDate(myitem.Name) = Date - 1
    Next myitem
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

This is how the slicers are formatted:

And this is a snippet of my current code:
Sub Slicerupdates()
    
    Sheets("FIP").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim targetSlicerCache As SlicerCache
    Dim currentPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim slicerIndex As Long
    
    Set targetSlicerCache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("slicer_Execution_Date1")
    
    For Each currentPivotTable In targetSlicerCache.PivotTables
        With currentPivotTable.PivotCache
            .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
            .Refresh
        End With
    Next currentPivotTable
    
    With targetSlicerCache
        .ClearManualFilter
        .SortItems = xlSlicerSortAscending
        For slicerIndex = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count - 1
            .SlicerItems(slicerIndex).Selected = False
        Next slicerIndex
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


I've tested the code without issue on M365.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

Try the following code...
Option Explicit

Sub maxdateslicer()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim targetSlicerCache As SlicerCache
    Dim currentPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim slicerIndex As Long
    Dim currentDate As Variant
    Dim maxDate As Date
    
    Set targetSlicerCache = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("slicer_Execution_Date1")
    
    For Each currentPivotTable In targetSlicerCache.PivotTables
        With currentPivotTable.PivotCache
            .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
            .Refresh
        End With
    Next currentPivotTable
    
    With targetSlicerCache
        .ClearManualFilter
        maxDate = getMaxDate(.SlicerItems)
        If maxDate > 0 Then
            For slicerIndex = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
                With .SlicerItems(slicerIndex)
                    currentDate = .Caption
                    If IsDate(currentDate) Then
                        If CDate(currentDate) <> maxDate Then
                            .Selected = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Private Function getMaxDate(ByVal slcrItems As SlicerItems) As Date

    Dim currentSlicerItem As SlicerItem
    Dim currentDate As Variant
    Dim maxDate As Date
    
    maxDate = 0
    For Each currentSlicerItem In slcrItems
        If currentSlicerItem.HasData Then
            currentDate = currentSlicerItem.Caption
            If IsDate(currentDate) Then
                currentDate = CDate(currentDate)
                If currentDate > maxDate Then
                    maxDate = currentDate
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next currentSlicerItem
    
    getMaxDate = maxDate
    
End Function


Thank you! This works perfectly, except I can't set each slicer property to false except the last one because this file adds new dates every time it runs. Is there a way to select the newly added slicer or the most recent date?

I woud suggest adding a line of code at the beginning of your routine to refresh the pivottable.  This way, when new data is added, you can simply run your macro so that the pivottable will be refreshed, and the latest date selected from the slicer.

I've added code above the previous code to refresh the pivot, but now it's just deselecting all slicers. Do you have any suggestions? I've been stumped on this for a while.

I'm still running into the same problem - it's just deselecting all slicers.

I have edited my post to amend the code.
